# How to compile and run SheepShaver on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, mac, emulation

I want to run [SheepShaver](https://sheepshaver.cebix.net/) PowerPC Mac emulator on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop.

How can I compile and run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One should install build-dependencies and development packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev x11proto-xf86dga-dev \
libesd0-dev libxxf86dga-dev libxxf86dga1 libsdl1.2-dev
```

*Note:* the `libesd0-dev` package is not available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Then clone official repository of the project and compile the application:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/cebix/macemu.git
cd macemu/SheepShaver
make links

cd src/Unix/
./autogen.sh
make -j3
```

Afterwards run it with `./SheepShaver`, and you will get the following window:

[image: SheepShaver under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS]

Comment: Tried in Ubuntu 18.0.4, but does not work. One of the listed packages is not available "E: Unable to locate package libesd0-dev", and the program itself crashes:

    "SheepShaver V2.4 by Christian Bauer and Mar"c" Hellwig
    ERROR: Cannot map Low Memory Globals: Operation not permitted.
   X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
      Major opcode of failed request:  105 (X_ChangePointerControl)
      Value in failed request:  0x0
      Serial number of failed request:  9
      Current serial number in output stream:  10"

Comment: Tried on clean 18.04 LTS - it compiles and runs successfully. I do not have ROMs, so I can't test further.

Comment: For what it's worth: PowerPC Macs came in 2 series: OldWorld and NewWorld machines. Broadly, NewWorld Macs had USB, but did not include a ROM with the classic MacOS Toolbox, as OS X did not use or require this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_World_ROM

PowerPC-only versions of classic (8.5 or greater) MacOS include a "NewWorld ROM" file as part of the OS installation files. This should work with SheepShaver.

Answer (score 1):

N.B. SheepShaver cannot run any version of MacOS later than 9.04 AFAIK. However this is long-obsolete and widely downloadable, e.g. https://winworldpc.com/product/mac-os-9/90

A pre-installed copy along with WordPerfect 3.5 for MacOS (the final version, made freeware by Corel when it discontinued Mac support) is included in this download: http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/mac-intel.html