# can't install sheep shaver emulator

Tags: cmake, emulation

so I was going to install sheep shaver to try out some old Mac OS games and I got to part the 2nd part of the install and I got this
checking for X... no, configure error: You need X11 to run Sheep Shaver.
if someone could help me with this it would help a lot thanks and bye

Comment: What release and flavor of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Are you running Wayland, rather than X?

Comment: Perhaps some hints here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1043864/57576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile and run SheepShaver on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043864/how-to-compile-and-run-sheepshaver-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)